# Attempting to use RestClient to sent POST request to elasticsearch

Tags: java, rest, http, elasticsearch, request

I have an elasticsearch cluster running on my port 9201. I want to send a POST request to it to retrieve some data using a query I have built. I have this code so far following elastic search's own api documentation. I am getting a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception`
This is being thrown at the line which is performing the request `Response response = restClient.performRequest(request);`

This is the code I have so far

```
try{
    RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")).build();
    Request request = new Request("POST", "/event/_search");
    request.setEntity(new NStringEntity(
                    "{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"action\":\"CREATE\"}}],\"must_not\":[],\"should\":[]}},\"from\":0,\"size\":10,\"sort\":[],\"aggs\":{}}",
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    Response response = restClient.performRequest(request);
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Even if I remove my `request.setEntity` line, I am getting the error.

Comment: I'm not sure the error is related to the query. Can you post the full stack trace please?

Comment: I actually figured out the problem. Somehow updating my pom.xml to hold older versions of elasticsearch solved the problem.